# How to decode Json column and divide the data in multiple columns and rows using SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in which one column is of data type Json and looks similar to the table shown below.

| Column 1 | Column 2 | SRC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | [ { "column_a": "12", "column_b": "3", "coulmn_c": ["abc"] }, { "column_a": "13", "column_b": "4", "coulmn_c": ["abd"] }, { "column_a": "14", "column_b": "5", "coulmn_c": ["abe"] }] |
| b | c | [ { "column_a": "11", "column_b": "1", "coulmn_c": ["bcd"] }] |

I want To decode the SRC column into three columns column_a,column_b,column_c and if one row has multiple values for these columns it should be divided in multiple rows

Now the Output should look Like :

| Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_A | COLUMN_B | COLUMN_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 12 | 3 | abc |
| a | b | 13 | 4 | abd |
| a | b | 14 | 5 | abe |
| a | b | 11 | 1 | bcd |

How can we achieve this using SQL ?

Comment: I believe the SRC column type is JSON and not "array"

Comment: COLUMN_C is an array. If it has more than one value do you want it in a separate row?

Comment: sorry i meant how to decode these type of column the data type i am using to store this column is array but its a JSON format column

Comment: Well, I'll post it decoding COLUMN_C as an array and you can see what I'm asking. It may need to be flattened more if there's more than one member in the array of COLUMN_C.

Comment: greg shows you how in his answer, but here is some documentation to explain it from snowflake -- https://www.snowflake.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Snowflake-How-to-Analyze-JSON-with-SQL.pdf

Answer (score 3):

This is a start, but the question is how to handle COLUMN_C. It's an array, so should that be returned as multiple rows or an array?

```
create or replace transient table T1(COLUMN1 string, COLUMN2 string, SRC variant);

insert into T1 select 
'a','b', parse_json($$[ { "column_a": "12", "column_b": "3", "coulmn_c": ["abc"] }, { "column_a": "13", "column_b": "4", "coulmn_c": ["abd"] }, { "column_a": "14", "column_b": "5", "coulmn_c": ["abe"] }]$$);

insert into T1 select 
'b','c', parse_json($$[ { "column_a": "11", "column_b": "1", "coulmn_c": ["bcd"] }]$$);


select   COLUMN1
        ,COLUMN2
        ,VALUE:column_a::int as COLUMN_A
        ,VALUE:column_b::int as COLUMN_B
        ,VALUE:coulmn_c::array as COLUMN_C
from T1, table(flatten(SRC));
```

If there's only one member of the COLUMN_C array, or you just want the first one, you can do this:

```
select   COLUMN1
        ,COLUMN2
        ,VALUE:column_a::int as COLUMN_A
        ,VALUE:column_b::int as COLUMN_B
        ,VALUE:coulmn_c::array[0]::string as COLUMN_C
from T1, table(flatten(SRC));
```

Comment: Greg can you explain how you are using the table keyword here -- what happens if you don't have it?

Comment: `table` is a keyword that wraps a table function. `flatten` is a table function, so one way to call it is using `table` as a wrapper. In this case if you don't have it you'll get a SQL syntax error. There are other ways to call the `flatten` function to signal to the compiler that it's a table function (such as using `lateral flatten`).